# How to store a List or Collection in a dataset table/column? (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, visual-studio-2013, dataset, datagridviewtextboxcell

I have a dataset table with various columns that are created during form load.
These columns are currently either system.double or system.string types.
And it is displayed in a datagridview.
This works fine.

But I need another column that can store a "list" or some collection in the data table.
A list of strings would do but a custom class would be better.

How is this usually done?

I have spent literally weeks googling this and I dont know where to start.  The more I have looked the more confused I have ended up.  I end up with more questions than answers, like how is it displayed in the datagridview? I read about a combo box?

I hope someone can give me some pointers in how to get this achieved.  I've not posted any code as I think its more the theory of this I need help with.

Comment: You are commingling the datastore with the implemention.  Generally, what you describe indicates a one-to-many relationship (a car has many parts, for instance).  So the List would likely be a new table in the DB, but perhaps a List(of Class) in code.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for has does have multiple concerns for most programmers. The storage of data (#1) and the displaying of said data to the user (#2)

For #1 I recommend the .net entity framework.  It gives support for storing, querying and updating classes for use in the database. Through most tutorials that I have found it is possible to model the structure of the database tables and their relations and then build a database around that model OR to use an existing database and create entities (entity framework's class objects) around the existing structures and relationships.

Here is a link to a very good beginner tutorial that I have used before: [CodeProject Entity Framework Tutorial for Absolute Beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363040/An-Introduction-to-Entity-Framework-for-Absolute-B)

For #2 I can recommend the Windows Presentation Foundation.  It has lots of bells and whistles to make using a data source and displaying the relevant dependent data very easily through its unique method of data binding.  From the tutorials I have used on [PluralSight](http://pluralsight.com) it can be as easy as dragging and dropping from an imported data source like the entity framework database.  Alternatively, one can just handle selected row changes for one data grid and then show the dependent data in another data grid.